# Why json have version 10.0.1 and 9.0.1 but there is not version of 9.0.0.0

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I spent more hours to fix this problem. I have research all ways in stackoverflow .I updated my json reference but. I couldn't solve this problem. Please help. Thanks in advance,Json version=9.0.0.0 is not fond.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 29:
>   Line 30:
>   Line 31:             var message = MessageResource.Create(
>   Line 32:
>   Line 33:                 to: to,
>   Source File: C:\Users\TexnoUsta\Documents\Visual Studio
>    2017\Projects\SANTEKSolutions\SANTEK.Web\Controllers\SmsController.cs
>   Line: 31
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:

Comment: Please observe the difference between the `assembly` tag and the `.net-assembly` tag.  The first is for ASM, the latter is for .Net assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for editing

Answer (score 0):

> Please help. Thanks in advance,Json version=9.0.0.0 is not fond.

Also if the version "9.0.1" exists, I would rather expect "9.0.0" than "9.0.0.0".

But according to github tags of source code: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tags, the "9.0.0[.0]" never existed, so you will never find it, unless you create your own.

Why? Ask the creator. But if the author of that package versions his code reasonably, then 9.0.1 should be minor bugfix of fictional 9.0.0, i.e. good-enough to be used by you as replacement for non-existing 9.0.0.0.

---

It looks like that web (?) already did use version 9.0.0.0 ... then ask the creator of the web, where did he get it from, maybe some custom creation, or from different company, building on the Newtonsoft.Json original, but releasing with different versions.

Comment: What do you offer? what is your solution for this exactly?

Comment: @SSadig: Change the web/app source to use 9.0.1 and rebuild+deploy/install update? Or even the latest 10.0.3, if it doesn't break anything and is backward compatible? I'm not C#/.net user, so I have no idea how building particular app works, and where dependencies+versions are specified, usually checking the source code is simplest way to figure things out.